# Dumping EPROCESS with windbg

Tags: windows, windows-7, windbg

I'm experimenting with LibVMI and Windows 7 32-bit; to properly set things up, I need to look at the first 8 bytes of an EPROCESS structure (the library searches memory for a magic number, this is supposed to be it).

My Windows-fu is not strong, so can anyone tell me how to dump the appropriate bit of memory? I'm running the local kernel debugger, and I've gotten as far as "dt nt!_EPROCESS" but that just seems to show me the format of the structure, not what's actually in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command is:

```
dt nt!_EPROCESS <address>
```

You should be able to obtain address from the output of the `!process 0 7`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out--Seva Titov's answer is similar to what I did. Here's how I did it:

`!process 0 0`

which gives me a short list of processes running; I had specifically started calc.exe to have a simple little program going, so I looked at the list and then ran:

`!process calc.exe`

The first line of output started like with `PROCESS 83f81178` which is the important bit. I then did:

`db 83f81178`

which showed me a chunk of memory starting at that offset, looking something like this:

`83f81178  03 00 26 00 00 00 00 00--80 11 f8 83 80 11 f8 83  ..&............`
`83f81188  88 11 f8 83 88 11 f8 83--80 23 e2 3e 00 00 00 00  ........#.>....`

That was what I needed, so I stopped there.